# in restructuredtext format, how to create a document title which is centered and not enumerated

Tags: restructuredtext

for example

```
==================
Title Document
==================
```

will create a left aligned title with enumeration such as

1. Title Document

I'm loooking form something to center the title in middle of the page and remove the enumeration

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in RST, as the details of formatting aren't of concern to the language itself. It's a text-structuring language with formatting *hints*, not a typesetting markup.

You don't even know how your RST is going to be rendered -- as HTML page? As series of slides? As PDF document? As built-in help for some programming tools?

Formatting is typically done by the respective renderer and is largely up to that renderer's discretion. Many popular renderers allow you, however, to supply style information externally (e.g. HTML renderers might allow you to supply CSS files that take care of beautifying things).

Comment: thanks for the reply, I checked another renderer, and it formatted the text in the way I prefer; so, I guess it depends on the renderer.